# how to troubleshoot problems with mysql query error # 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

I spring to apply the method of vector space model and want to calculate using a function like this

```
SELECT SQRT (SUM (POW (SUM (tb_kata_sara.IDF), 2)))
FROM tb_detail, tb_kata_sara
WHERE tb_detail.id_kata_sara = tb_kata_sara.id_kata_sara
AND tb_detail.id_tweet = 159
GROUP BY tb_kata_sara.id_kata_sara
```

I've tried a few other variations but still unsolved

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want this query:

```
SELECT SQRT(SUM(POW(sumIDF, 2)))
FROM (SELECT SUM(is.IDF) as sumIDF
      FROM tb_detail d JOIN
           tb_kata_sara ks
           ON d.id_kata_sara = ks.id_kata_sara
      WHERE d.id_tweet = 159
      GROUP BY ks.id_kata_sara
     ) x;
```

Note:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.